# Yet another bash that needs explanation

Tags: bash, unix, find

Here another bash command that needs some explanation. Can someone explain what are does the option means for the $find command mean? I know that the command finds file with 0 bytes and throw them away.

```
$find . – type f –size 0 | xargs rm ls -ld
```

what does the . mean?
What does the | mean?

what does    - type f - size 0

what is xargs ?

what does - ld mean?

rm = remove
ls = list

Comment: xargs splits the listing into sublists. find . means start from the current dir. f specifies file, i.e. not soft of hard links, or special files, or drivers. Use apropos find. apropos xargs

Comment: Your command appears to be improperly formatted. It will not work as you have typed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find takes one parameter: the directory to use as the root for the search. All other paramters are passed in as options.

```
find . -type f -size 0

find     :  The name of the program.
.        :  The directory to use as the root for the search.
-type f  :  Find only regular files. (Excludes directories, sym links, etc.)
-size 0  :  Finds only empty files.
```

The output from the find command will be a list of empty files. This output is then fed into xargs. xargs is a program that takes a list of strings as input and then performs a given command on all of them.

The command `xargs rm ls -ld` you have typed out appears erroneous. I will use `xargs rm` as an example instead.

```
xargs rm

xargs    :  The name of the program.
rm       :  The command to run on each file.
```

Thus the full command `find . -type f -size 0 | xargs rm` finds all empty files and deletes them.

Answer (score 3):

`.` is the current directory

`|` *pipes* the output of one command (find) into the input of another (xargs)

I would suggest that you use `man find`, `man xargs` and `man ls` to determine what the options are for `find` and what exactly `xargs` and `ls` are doing.